# How to load EBCDIC file into relational tables ( Oracle, SQL Server etc.) using Informatica Power Center

Tags: ascii, informatica, mainframe, ebcdic, informatica-powerexchange

I have a mainframe source file in EBCDIC format. I need to load it in Oracle database . We also have Informatica Power Center and SSIS ETL tools.

What is the easiest way to load it in relational tables using or without using above tools? How to decode this file?

Note- when I open this file, I see all weird symbols ( this is a text file but in EBCDIC format so I can not understand any of the data in this file). It's a sequential file and I also have a Cobol Layout file along with it.

Comment: In what format is the data to be loaded in?  CSV delimited, is it all text data, are there binary formats of data, is it record based?  That info will help answer your question.  The simple answer is use `iconv` to convert the data from EBCDIC to UTF-8 or ASCII.  Remember, there are multiple codepages for EBCDIC data so you need to know if its 037, 1047 or some other variant

Comment: Its a sequential file. I also have a Cobol Layout file with it. If i open the EBCDIC file, I see some weird symbols . All of this data is text in reality but due to EBCDIC format all these characters are present. How can I convert it into actual text data?

Comment: Are you sure that it is all text? Packed decimal will produce 'weird symbols'. You need to unpack packed decimal fields into display fields.

Comment: Can you share a "santized" version of the copybook?  Or, if not, list all of the PIC and type (X, 9 and numeric types like COMP, COMP-3, ...)